# Symfony: FMElfinderBundle + IvoryCKEditorBundle. Blank page

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, elfinder

I use IvoryCKEditorBundle in a symfony project without any problems.

But whan I try adding FMElfinderBundle to IvoryCKEditorBundle. I get a blank page with errors in the console:

[image]

My code:

```
#app/config/config.yml
# FMElfinderBundle Configuration
fm_elfinder:
    instances:
        ckeditor:
            locale: %locale% # defaults to current request locale
            editor: ckeditor # other options are tinymce, tinymce4, form, custom and simple
            fullscreen: true # defaults true, applies to simple and ckeditor editors
            theme: smoothness # jquery theme
            include_assets: true # disable if you want to handle loading of the javascript and css assets yourself
            connector:
                debug: false # defaults to false
                roots:       # at least one root must be defined
                    uploads:
                        show_hidden: false # defaults to false
                        driver: LocalFileSystem
                        path: uploads
                        upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
                        upload_deny: ['all']
                        upload_max_size: 2M

# IvoryCKEditorBundle Configuration
ivory_ck_editor:
    default_config:    my_custom_config
    configs:
        my_custom_config:
            toolbar:                    full
            filebrowserBrowseRoute:     elfinder
            filebrowserBrowseRouteParameters:
                instance: ckeditor
```

Any help?? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is my config. Maybe it helps:

```
fm_elfinder:
    instances:
        default:
            locale: %default_locale% # defaults to current request locale
            editor: ckeditor # other options are tinymce, tinymce4, form, custom and simple
            fullscreen: true # defaults true, applies to simple and ckeditor editors
            theme: smoothness # jquery theme
            include_assets: true # disable if you want to handle loading of the javascript and css assets yourself
            connector:
                debug: false # defaults to false
                roots:       # at least one root must be defined
                    uploads:
                        show_hidden: false # defaults to false
                        driver: LocalFileSystem
                        path: uploads/content
                        upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
                        upload_deny: ['all']
                        upload_max_size: 20M

ivory_ck_editor:
    configs:
        my_config:
            removePlugins: 'flash,print,forms,div,newpage'
            allowedContent: true
            entities: false
            autoParagraph: false
            protectedSource: ['/<span[^>]*><\/span>/g', '/<i[^>]*><\/i>/g']
```

Comment: Hey, this works for me, but now i can't upload files from my computer, only links works ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that elfinder assets didn't properly dumped, check assets folder under web root directory. Also check that your composer file contains

```
{
    "config": {
        "component-dir": "web/assets"
    }
}
```

This part tell component installer to copy assets under web/assets directory.